# Gatsby fetch data from local storage best practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I would like to fetch data from local storge (in runtime) every time the app starts, then I store it in a store.

Gatsby docs explain the way to do this:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/data-fetching/

Basically just use the useEffect hook in a page and get the data from local storage. However, I would like to get this data independently of the page being visited. For example, if I fetch the data on the index page, and the user refreshes another page, the data won't be fetched. **I would like to do it in the equivalent of App.tsx file in a regular React app**.

My current solution is to do it in wrap-pages file:

```
const MyLocalStorage = ({ children }) => {
  const { getLocalStorage} = fromStore()

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalStorage() // fetches data from local storage
  }, [])
  return null
}

export function wrapPagesDeep({ element }) {
  return (
    <>

        <MyLocalStorage/>
        {element}

    </>
  )
}
```

This however doesn't make much sense. This file is intended for wrapping components, not for data fetching. What would be the correct way to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways depending on your architecture, design system, and use cases (for example, from a provider to a wrapper, from an isolated service to a controller, etc.).

There is no such thing as "best practice" without knowing everything involved in the decision: making some super complicated and isolated logic (like adding an MVVM: controller, stores, etc.)  may look good but can be an extremely bad practice for a simple scenario, and vice-versa: an easy and straightforward approach can be a bad solution for a complex app.

Following your approach, I think it could be easily isolated (and reused) by moving this logic into a `Layout` (or a wrapper that wraps your application) and adding a [`location` prop](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) to it. Something like:

```
const Layout = ({ children, location = {} }) => {
  const { getLocalStorage} = fromStore()

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalStorage() // fetches data from local storage
  }, [location])

  return (
    <>
        <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Then, in every use of `Layout`:

```
const SomePage = ({ location }) => {
  return (
    <Layout location={location}>
      <h1>Some content</h1>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

*Note: `location` prop is inherited by default in all top-level components (pages and templates) as you can see in the docs*

So every time the location changes, you will fetch the local storage data. This can be easily moved to a provider that updates the value automatically. You will only need to wrap your application accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I came to the conclusion that this type of solution won't be efficient because it means that the data will be fetched on every route, because Layout will wrap each page probably. I ended up using the old syntax I wrote in my question, just using gatsby-browser file and fetching inside the function wrapRootElement so data is fetched only once. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: I thought that's was the point. You can always add a condition inside the `useEffect`  though to only trigger it in the desired pages like: `if(['desired-trigger-page', 'desired-trigger-page-2' ].includes(location.pathname)){ // fetch localStorage }`